# How to distinguish primary hosts (stars) and orbiting satellites (planets) and tertiary bodies (moons) by their mass and trajectory?

Tags: python, computational-physics, computational-geometry, numerical-modelling, graph-theory

I posted this question in the astronomy stackexchange. There are no responses, and it was suggested that I pose the question here. The "too long, didn't read" was taken from a comment, and my question is copy-pasted below.

[TLDR](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/43871/how-to-distinguish-primary-hosts-stars-and-orbiting-satellites-planets-and-t#comment90139_43871):

> You're asking about how some kind of classifier might work that
> accepts a group of trajectories or state vectors for  bodies over an
> extended period of time, and identifies orbital hierarchies; i.e. "Who
> orbits who orbits who?"

Suppose one has run a gravitational simulation of `N` bodies (has the mass, vector positions, vector velocities, etc for each body), but knows nothing *a priori* about the system (ie, one does not know anything regarding composition, or which bodies are stars or planets). I would like to use the simulation results to categorize which bodies are primary hosts and which ones are satellites (and if possible, which "tertiary" bodies are orbiting the satellites). **Is there a way to create a hierarchy that identifies whether a body is a primary host or satellite or tertiary?** I would like to find a method of doing this such that the method can be applied to cases for `N > 10^3` bodies.

For context, consider a `9`-body system like a simplified example of our solar system (`8` planets + `1` star). One can identify the Sun as the only primary host and the planets as the satellites because the ratio of the mass of the Sun to the mass of Jupiter (most massive planet of our solar system) [is 1048](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mass%20of%20sun%20%2F%20mass%20of%20jupiter). One could also use the approach of noticing that the center of mass would be inside of the Sun (or very close to in a point-mass simulation). But, the center of mass approach only works for nearly circular stable orbits around a single host; for unstable orbits, a body can deviate from its tangential path about the center of mass.

If we consider a binary star system for which both stars are of comparable mass, then *I think that* the ratio of the mass of any single host star to the mass of the most massive planet orbiting this binary star system can decrease; in other words, for each primary host body added to a system, the combined gravitational force at certain points in the orbit required to keep a satellite body in orbit should decrease *if the system is stable*, thereby decreasing the ratio of the mass of any host body to the mass of the most massive satellite body. (I suppose the same logic could be extended to host planets and satellite moons, though I suspect the ratio of masses would decrease; would this logic also apply to unstable orbits?)

Is this line of thinking correct? More importantly, what is the right way to think about this?

Comment: What is the definition of primary host and satellite? In general the motion of 3+ body system can be very complex, not periodic, so you cannot tell what is orbiting what.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Say I have bodies A, B, and C. If A is orbiting B, then A is a satellite of B, and B is the host of A. Suppose B is orbiting C as well - then B is a satellite of C, and C is a host to B. In such a case, I would consider C to be the primary host because C does not orbit about another body (though it orbits the center of mass of the system). The simplest possible scenario for this could be A=moon, B=planet, C=star; though others can exist. For my purposes, this doesn't matter - I just want the hierarchy. Rogue bodies (for lack of better word) would have their own classification.

Comment: I think machine learning methods like classification, or possibly clustering are in order here.

Comment: @zeebeel If there is no significant separation of masses then there is no "regular" motion when something is orbiting something else, it will be chaotic motion like in a nonideal gas where there are attraction forces between molecules, for each object the trajectory would be something irregular around the common center of mass. Take a look at Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem, they show an animation that illustrates it well.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I realize the orbits can be chaotic, so they may not follow nice keplerian trajectories. What I do not understand is why a body in a chaotic orbit (like the chaotic 3-body in the wiki animation) cannot have its own classification (ie, 3 primary hosts with no secondaries or tertiaries).

Comment: This problem seems like it can be solved, if you can determine whether a given object is in the orbit of another object. Then using the centre of mass as the frame of reference, there is a hierarchy: primaries only orbit the centre of mass, secondaries orbit the centre of mass in addition to one or more primaries, tertiaries orbit the centre of mass, some primaries and some secondaries. Effective potential may be a tool to determine if something is in the orbit of something else, but my physics is first-year undergrad level. So don't trust me; verify.

Comment: @zeebeel Your problem statement is meaningful only if there is large mass separation between stars, planets, and moons. If the Earth and the Moon had the same mass then you would not be able to tell what orbits what, right? And if they both had the same mass as the Sun then you would not be able to tell which one is the host, right? Your system with 1e3 bodies, if they had the same mass, would look like a gas of randomly moving molecules interacting by gravity forces (there is a word for this "gravitational plasma").

Comment: The key notion you are using in your problem description and comments is "A is *orbiting* B". But you don't define what "is orbiting" actually means, and there lies the problem: It is easy to see as a human if A is orbiting B, but hard to describe in terms of rules a computer could follow. Moreover, and as has been pointed out above, "A is orbiting B" implies a large mass difference between A and B, and that would already suggest a classification algorithm: Just look at the masses of the objects and apply a clustering algorithm.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, I was thinking about "orbiting" because of this question and I noticed that it took until Copernicus, Kepler and Galileo to be undoubtedly conclude that Earth orbits the sun and not vice versa. I don't know any way to mathematically measure if something is in the orbit of another thing (my ignorance, probably someone already figured it out). I thought effective potential could work, but that approach apparently has issues since it is an approximation.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas The issue is that in both a star-planet system and a binary star system, both bodies "orbit" the common center of mass. In neither system does one body "orbit the other body". The phrase "A orbits B" only makes sense in the limit of the ratio of the mass of A to the mass of B becoming zero, or at least being very small. In other words, if there is a clear gap in the distribution of masses in a system. Short of that, you will have a very difficult time to define "orbit". Just look at the trajectories of stars in a star cluster.